# Padding-left for drop cap

Tags: html, css

[Image of drop cap that is offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcvLu.png)

How can I set the padding-left as I have below but without doing it in a paragraph. my firstcharacter class creates a drop cap but the left padding is off so I fixed that with the 5px left padding. Only problem is that it pushes the text down an entire line as a new paragraph.

```
<span class="firstcharacter">H</span><p style="padding-left:     
5px;">eadquartered in Seattle Washingon, yada yada.</p>
```

Screenshot added. The drop cap is still a bit off to the right. This is on Squarespace.com and I am not sure if something else there is messing this up. I tried the above and had the same issue and now I am back to this:

```
p.drop-cap:first-letter {
color: #903;
float: left;
font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 60px;
padding-top: 8px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-left: 0px;
```

}

Comment: [The `text-indent` property accepts both positive and negative values.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) You can also assign styles to [`:first-line`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) and [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter)

Comment: add display:inline-block; to p

Comment: try applying "whitespace: none;" to your p tag to prevent it from a line break.

Comment: tried this but didn't change anything. <p style="padding-left: 5px; whitespace: none">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying `:first-letter` styles to the paragraph instead. You can `float` the first letter so it stays inline with the rest of the paragraph.

```css
p.drop-cap:first-letter {
font-size: 60px;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<p class="drop-cap">Headquartered in Seattle Washingon, yada yada. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
```

Comment: I couldn't find a way to add code in my comment so I edited my original question with what I have now. I tried the p.drop-cap as you suggested but either way I have the same issue. What I have not gets me the closet so far.  I was able to get this working last night by wrapping a <p> around each paragraph on the page and setting padding left to 5px but that ended up putting  newline before the first paragraph which I don't want. so if there is a way to do that without the newline that will work as well. thanks.

Comment: Your dropcap [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcvLu.png) is positioned correctly, but the letter itself has a certain amount of space. You can fix this using `position:relative` and a positive of negative `left:` value, or by applying negative left and right margins to the letter.

Comment: Would you be able to show me how to do this? i put the position:relative in my css and it completely messed up the drop cap. thank you.

Comment: I actually got it working using the margin-left of -5px. is there a way to add code to my comment here? i didn't see anything in the help about that. thanks.

Comment: That should be fine. Don't forget to accept your favorite answer when you're all done (please!).